# Chainlink jobs returns error if external adapter takes too long for response

Tags: blockchain, chainlink, toml

I am encountering this error when running a job via my own chainlink node even though the external adapter is returning the data properly.
`HTTP request timed out or interrupted`
This error is triggered during the "fetch" function of the job.
I have figured that the error is triggered because my external adapter is taking some time to respond.
Is there any way I can make my chainlink node wait longer?

I tried a response with dummy data that did not require any API to fetch and the job ran perfectly.
The error has been fixed by the given answer.

However now after the job sends the data back to my oracle, FulfillOracleRequest2 is not executing.
[image: This is the transaction of my operator.sol oracle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT setting in your nodes configuration

https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/configuration#default_http_timeout

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, it worked like a charm after updating DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT in my .env file. The job is running successfully now.

Comment: Hey I have edited my question. Do you know why fulfill oracle request2 is not executing even though job has run successfully

Comment: Is a transaction being generated? does it show any errors when you look at it in etherscan? Suggest checking the log nodes to see if there's any errors there.

Comment: Yes the transaction is generated. I have attacked the screenshot of the transaction with the question